# Erro ao criar um conjunto de replica no MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicação

Estou montando um conjunto de réplica de instâncias mongod, o nodo primário inciou perfeitamente. Mas os demais nodos que deveriam aparecer como secudários não estão mundando de estado.

[image: O resultado do comando rs.status() no nodo primário]

E quando eu verifico em cada um dos nodos, em um eu tenho isso como resultdo:

[![O resultado do comando db.isMaster() num dos nodos secundário][2]][2]

Alguém teria uma ideia do problema que pode estar por trás disso? Grato!

Comment: Você pode postar seu arquivo de configuração usado no replicaSet ?

Comment: Sim, claro. Postei o print do arquivo de configuração que estou usando.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O arquivo de configuração que usei no replicaSet

Comment: Este arquivo esta me parecendo um de configuração do Mongo. Cola o resultado to comando rs.conf() sendo executado no teu mongod primario.

Comment: O comando rs.conf() me está me mostrando todos os nodos que adicionei no meu replicaSet.

Comment: Tentou descomentar o bind_ip=0.0.0.0 ? Um dos motivos que leva esta trava no status dos nó é uma falta de comunicação entre os servidores, onde cada nó tem que se comunicar com os demais nós e com ele mesmo, o bind_ip pode levar a este problema, como também o domain. Vou tentar replicar o teu problema.

Comment: Eu descomentei mas recebe um warning de que não erra necesário colocar isso porque por default ele escuta em todas as inferfaces. Por isso que aparece agora comentado no arquivo de configuração.

Comment: Estranho, eu vou simular o teu mesmo ambiente e te dou um retorno assim que tiver pronto. Pois tudo parece ok e ate onde eu sei o que pode levar a este tipo de problema é a comunicação entre os servers, que não parece ser o teu caso.

Comment: Os nodos se enxergam porque se não estivessem, nem o comando rs.add() ia ter sucesso. Mas vou aguardar um retorno. Por ora, já te agradeço pela tentativa de ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O print do comando rs.conf() no nodo primário